# using a validation with has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to set up a validation so that people can't submit a post unless they click on a category for that post and also to make sure that they can chose only one of the categorys for that post so the post can have only one category. Here are the modles

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

  validates :title, :content, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 140 }
end
```

also here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="animated tada">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "post[category_ids][]", nil%>
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %><br>
    <%= check_box_tag "post[category_ids][]", category.id, @post.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category)%>
  <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

do any of you know what I would need to put in to make my form come back with a message saying need to select category or can pick only one category?

Answer (score 0):

We've done a similar thing with `has_many :through`

---

**Validating On The Join Model**

Our solution was to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and validate on the join model. This could be seen as quite inefficient, but works well for us:

```
#app/models/message.rb
Class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :body,
         :presence => { :message => "Needs A Value!" }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_subscribers, :allow_destroy => true
end

#app/models/message_subscriber.rb
Class MessageSubscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Validations
    validates :subscriber_id,
           :presence => { :message => "Your Message Needs Subscribers!" }
end
```

This returns an error if you don't have any `subscriber_id`'s selected

---

**Your Code**

For you, I'd be tempted to do this:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category

  #Validation
  validates :subscriber_id, :presence => { :message => "You need to select a category!" }
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

  #Validation
  validates :title, :content, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 140 }

end
```

I was going to include `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for you, but I realized it would be an inconvenient way to do something you're doing already. In light of this, I believe you may be best suited just performing the validations in your join model, however if it does not work, we'll add the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` functionality